# Change of sorting order when results displayed on Google Chrome vs. Mozilla Firefox

Tags: java, google-chrome, sorting, firefox, criteria

I am sorting the tasks from back-end (java) using  javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery.orderBy(Order... o) method based on task's due dates in ascending order.No additional pipe or filter has been used in front-end(angular). The sorted results should be displayed in UI as such. If i am using Mozilla Firefox (55.0.3 (64-bit)) the results are displayed in the sorted order. ***But if am using Google Chrome (Version 61.0.3163.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)) the sorting order changes to some random pattern which i can't make out***.

Am i missing something out here ? Do some browsers have their own in-built sorting mechanism or algorithm which they use to override the sorting results ? If yes, how can we override that and stabilize the sorting order across different browsers.

I am using the latest versions of both the browsers (Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox) in case you are wondering.I have not tested this across any other browser so far.

Here's a snippet of my code for your ready reference :

```
public void checkTaskCategory(TaskCriteria criteria, CriteriaBuilder cb, CriteriaQuery<Task> q, Root<Task> task,
        List<Predicate> predicates) {
    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(criteria.getCategory())) {
        ParameterExpression<LocalDate> currentDate = cb.parameter(LocalDate.class, "currentDate");
        if (StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase(TaskConstants.TASK_OVERDUE, criteria.getCategory())) {
            predicates.add(cb.greaterThan(currentDate, task.<LocalDate>get(TaskConstants.DUE_DATE)));
            predicates.add(cb.notEqual(task.get("status"), getStatus(Status.Value.DONE.toString()).getId()));
            q.orderBy(cb.asc(task.get(TaskConstants.DUE_DATE)));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it seems to be `java` not `javascript`

Comment: @Ravi ya..thanks for the pointing that out. Any possible reason ?

Comment: Any help will be appreciated. Anyone ?